# How to use result from a script shell with applescript?

Tags: shell, applescript

I'm trying to run a simple code from applescript.

It use blueutil, a command-line utility that can query Bluetooth’s status (on or off) /  turn it on /  turn it off.

I try this code from rob cottingham:

```
tell application “Terminal”
do shell script “/usr/local/bin/blueutil status”
set _Result tothe result
if _Result is “Status: on” then
do shell script “/usr/local/bin/blueutil off”
endif
if _Result is “Status: off” then
do shell script “/usr/local/bin/blueutil on”
endif
endtell
```

Without success.
If i clean all and only keep the lines about turning off or on, it works though.

Cleanest code I seems to get is:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/blueutil status"
    
    set theResult to the result
    if "result" is "Status: on" then
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/blueutil off"
    end if
    
end tell
```

But still doesn't work.

Maybe it's about using the result of the query as a variable?

I'm really not a professional it as you probably guessed, so any help will be appreciated !
Thanks,
Christophe.

Comment: You can declare/define variables using `set theResult to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/blueutil status"`. However, I've tried to execute `blueutil status` in my terminal and apparently the argument Status doesn't exist.

Comment: Also note that **Terminal** is not needed when using `do shell script`.

Comment: @red_menace still, blueutil has no argument called status. I think OP is searching for `blueutil -p`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't need Terminal.app at all.

Second of all there is no argument `status`, to get the power state write:

```
set powerStatus to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p" as boolean
```

The result is `true` or `false`.

---

To toggle the power state write:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p toggle"
```

To set the power state to on:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p on"
```

To set the power state to off:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p off"
```

Yes, it's just one line respectively.

---

And you can get the help message showing the man page.

```
set helpText to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/blueutil -h"
```